# Nullable Data type validation and IValidatableObject.Validate method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Model like below

```
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [DisplayName("Property Name")]
    [Range(0, 9999999, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number between 0 and 9999999")]
    public int? PropName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    { 
        if (this.PropName == null)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Property Name is NOT entered");
        }
    }
}
```

In the view,

1. When I enter an integer value, I dont see the error message "Property Name is NOT  entered"
2. When I leave the field blank, I see the error message "Property Name is NOT entered"
3. When I enter a decimal value, I see the error messages below

   - The value 'xx.xx' is not valid for Property Name.
   - Property Name is NOT entered

For case 3, I certainly did not expect to see the message from Validate() method. i.e the Validate() method should have never fired when there is an error with data type.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

The view just uses @Html.ValidationSummary() to display the messages.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find documentation on the order of the field validation, field binding to values, and `Validate` executing when model binding. However, I think the fields are being bound to their values before `Validate` executes. Therefore `PropName` is null in `Validate`.

This means the order of events for `PropName` when entered as decimal is:

1. Error generated for wrong datatype
2. Set to null
3. Error generated for being null

Have you tried using `RequiredAttribute` instead of your custom validation? This would mean you don't need to implement `IValidatableObject` and your code becomes

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Property Name")]
    [Range(0, 9999999, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a number between 0 and 9999999")]
    public int? PropName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I cannot really use the `[Required]` attribute as the actual validation that I have is much more complex than what I have illustrated above. The above is just sample to explain flow. Until now I believed that the `IValidatableObject.Validate()` will never fire when there is a Data annotations error and I assumed data type error also follows the same logic. But clearly it is not so.

Comment: `Validate` is a class level validation method. The data annotations perform field level validations. If one field fails validation then the others are still all checked and all the errors returned. So it would make sense that `Validate` always fires even when some fields have errors.